# Trouble sorting pandas columns by label, no methods seem to work for me?

Tags: python, pandas

As part of a larger project I need to gather a large amount of data, fix any nan values, organise them then plot them. Pandas seems like an ideal package to do this with. I'm having difficulty getting my latest test batch to behave, however.

My column labels are all numbers, so it shouldn't be difficult to sort these in ascending order, but for some reason python is just refusing to. This then causes problems for plotting using matplotlib as I'm plotting a 2D surface in 3D using the meshgrid function. To my knowledge the meshgrid function is dependent on the order you feed it the data as it plots connections between successive points. I certainly get some very strange plots when I don't first order my data. The labels are going in as floats, is this being changed somehow?

My pandas dataframe is first created from a nested dictionary using:

```
def create_table(nested_dict):
"""Takes a dict of dicts where each outer key is a Tb value, each inner 
key is a Sbma value and innermost value is a
xsection value, then creates a table from them"""

data_table = df.from_dict(nested_dict)
data_table = data_table.transpose()
data_table = data_table.reindex(sorted(data_table.columns), axis=1)
data_table = data_table.reindex(sorted(data_table.index), axis=0)
data_table = data_table.sort_index(axis = 1)
       
return data_table
```

This is successful in ordering the rows (though there are only 3 of them so this isn't saying much) and transposing the dataframe. But when it comes to the columns it seems like it has something strange going on. Printing it out I have:

```
             0.5       1.0       1.5      10.0      10.5      11.0      11.5  \
```

0.9000  0.266542  0.085487  0.051862  0.027435  0.027684  0.027948  0.028239
0.9500  0.261763  0.084601  0.051343  0.027570  0.027816  0.028064  0.028327
0.9999  0.255504  0.082071  0.049922  0.027659  0.027885  0.028145  0.028445

```
        12.0      12.5      13.0  ...       5.0       5.5       6.0  \
```

0.9000  0.028544  0.028875  0.029229  ...  0.027334  0.027015  0.026793
0.9500  0.028633  0.029008  0.029321  ...  0.027317  0.027025  0.026882
0.9999  0.028636  0.028956  0.029299  ...  0.027136  0.026886  0.026740

```
         6.5       7.0       7.5       8.0       8.5       9.0       9.5
```

0.9000  0.026603  0.026628  0.026756  0.026827  0.026950  0.027081  0.027284
0.9500  0.026757  0.026731  0.026785  0.026866  0.027007  0.027170  0.027372
0.9999  0.026689  0.026708  0.026764  0.026883  0.027023  0.027233  0.027404

[3 rows x 62 columns]

The columns contained within the "..." have values above those shown, I'm not sure what's going on! (Also I realise I have two lines in my function for reordering my columns, the second was simply added because the first was no longer working!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right that you want to sort your index twice? If your data_table is correct after the line `df.from_dict(nested_dict)` than this should do it for you.

```
data_table = data_table.sort_index(axis=0).sort_index(axis=1)
data_table
```

Please try it.

Comment: It turns out I didn't check if the labels were strings or not thoroughly enough, once I did your suggestion worked, thanks!